# 'I'm sure your friends will likely call you on your birthday.' Is "that" required?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, that, subordinators

Could someone please help me.

I was wondering if I have to use "that" in the following sentence:

> I'm sure your friends will likely call you on your birthday.

Should there be a "that" between ***sure*** and ***friends***?

Thank you.

Comment: Leaving it out is more natural in speech, but in both speech and writing, either way is OK.

Comment: There are many cases where the use of "that" is optional.

Comment: @deadrat I posted another duplicate question. I think it is better as the omitted that is not a relative pronoun. :-)

Comment: @deadrat Erm, definitely not Mr Deadrat! The word *that* isn't a relative pronoun in the OP's sentence. It's a subordinator.

Comment: @Rathony I'm not sure that's a good page to link to because it's a mishmash of relative *that*, pronoun *that* and subordinator *that*. The subordinator *that* does not get a good treatment on that page, in my opinion (see my answer here for comparison).

Comment: @Araucaria How can I possibly disagree with you? But isn't the question for ELL?

Comment: @Rathony I think that the behaviour of the subordinators is probably of interest to linguists if handled in an appropriate way. It would fit on ELL too no doubt :-)

Comment: @deadrat See below for more detail :)

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed. For details of when, see below!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure your friends will likely call you on your birthday

In the sentence above, the phrase *your friends will likely call you on your birthday* is a Complement of the adjective *sure*. This type of clause is known as a content clause (as opposed to a relative clause, or a comparative clause).

Content clauses are often introduced by the subordinator *that*:

- I know [that you ate my last chocolate biscuit].

We only use *that* with declarative content clauses, not interrogative ones or exclamative ones:

- *I wonder that if she is going to the party. (ungrammatical)
- *I saw that how big the elephant was! (ungrammatical)

**When to use *that* in declarative content clauses**

We always use *that* with a content clause when a content clause is the Subject of a sentence:

- [That you were late again] will not impress the powers that be.
- *[You were late again] will not impress the powers that be. (ungrammatical)

We also always use *that* if the content clause has been moved to a position before the Subject:

- [That I need help] I freely admit.

The sentence above is a version of *I freely admit that I need help*, where the Complement of admit has been moved to before the Subject, *I*.

We rarely use *that* if the content clause is the Complement of a preposition:

- I will see you after you've finished your meeting.
- *I will see you after that you have finished your meeting. (ungrammatical)

[There are a handful of very unusual prepositions such as *notwithstanding* which allow *that*.]

In nearly all other cases where the content clause is the Complement of a verb, noun, or adjective the word *that* is optional. It can be omitted or included as you see fit:

- I know that you ate my biscuits.
- I know you ate my biscuits.
- I'm happy you ate my biscuits
- I am happy that you ate my biscuits.
- The fact you ate my biscuits really gets my goat.
- The fact that you ate my biscuits really gets my goat.

We are far more likely to omit *that* if it's the Complement of a simple high frequency verb, adjective or noun. We are also far less likely to omit *that* in formal writing:

- The notion you ate my biscuit is laughable. (slightly awkward because of *notion*)
- We therefore need to underline we are going to be there. (awkward because formal and because of the long as well as low frequency verb *underline*)

**Conclusion**

In the Original Poster's sentence the content clause is the complement of the simple and high frequency adjective *sure*. The context is also not formal. The Original Poster can therefore freely omit *that*. The sentence will be both grammatical and appropriate.

---

**References**

<sup>Most of this information is available in:</sup> <sup>[*A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar) Huddleston & Pullum, 2005.</sup>

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the distinction between exclamative and declarative. For instance: "I was told who is going to the party" and "I was told how big the elephant is." Are these exclamative? They can't take a *that* either. Is there perhaps a simpler rule, like don't mix a *who* or *how* with a *that*?

Comment: @Jacinto That kind of rule might end up being a bit more complicated. Your sentences are actually types of fused relative constructions (relative clauses without antecedents). Probably a good rule of thumb is don't use *that* with interrogative *if* or with a wh-word, if the wh-word is at the front of a single clause. If the wh-clause is embedded in a larger clause, then you might be able to use *that*: "We know that [who did it] is not the main problem". Here you can use *that* because the following wh-clause is part of a larger declarative clause "[wh-clause] is not the problem".